# How to clean low-quality content?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, user-accounts

I agree that I posted low quality content but I did it to solve real technical problems which all are solved now. Now I don't have actual technical problems but I wanted to ask about MIPS processors here but now this site no longer accepts questions from me because of this specific question ("How to clean the AppData directory from ransomware") which got downvoted enough to end my ability to ask here:

https://superuser.com/questions/558744

The question is bad but it's a real problem and not bogus and the user of the system that we fixed is reporting today that his system "works perfect" so I still think it's sort of a real question how I can delete as much as ½ GB data and the user reports the system "works perfect".

I agree that I posted "low quality" content and that my writing and style and questions and answers are bad and poor and is of low interest to others but I still don't think my account is a troll or a phony or scam spam account.

If you look at my questions you see that I had phone and laptop problem which I also think is low quality content. So all my questions about Samsung Galaxy for instance can have been random error or just me misunderstanding the usage.

If the content I posted is "low quality" which I agree it is then what's the advantage keeping it?

If I answer questions well can I balance back my account to a good one or is my account disabled forever now?

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Comment: For what it's worth, a single question is not going to land you a question-ban. Any questions that have been deleted count, too. To lift the ban, your only options are to improve your existing posts (so that they get upvotes) and/or post useful answers. Oh, and you might try posting Android questions at [android.se]. Android questions are only on-topic here when it's in relation to connecting the device to a PC or local network.

Comment: Thanks a lot that I at least still can ask here. I'm glad that improvement is still allowed even though I'm banned. I think this network is the best Q+A sites and I confess that I posted low quality content. I don't think I posted anything scammy, spammy or phony but I feel that I did post some low quality content in order to solve technical problem which now de facto is solved.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz - The question you linked to can be improved upon. A few ways would be to include the log showing which malware was found, showing a screenshot of property dialog on the folder in question, improve the quality of the writting within the question itself. You could even ask how to determine what data is and is not required in the folder. You also went into details within your comments and never updated your question, makes those changes and I will remove the the downvote that I casted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have quite entirely missed the scope of Super User! That's a shame considering you have nearly 4k reputation on Stack Overflow. Have you read our FAQ?

Read the link Oliver Salzburg posted for help lifting the question ban. You also need to make sure that future answers and questions do not follow the same pattern as your old posts.

I don't want you to feel personally attacked here, that is not my intention whatsoever, but you *have* consistently posted low quality and off topic material. I'm going to pick through some of the questions that stand out to me by their titles and try to explain. While I do this, please keep in mind that I don't want to run you off or make you feel unwelcome. Clearly you're doing something right on SO and my intent is to help you become a valuable member of the SU community as well.

<sub>(For other readers: I've neglected to add links to these questions intentionally. I see no need to flag, downvote, or vote to close these questions as this user is already question banned. We don't need to dig his hole any deeper.)</sub>

---

#### Which trackers to use for a torrent? [closed]

I can only speculate the method used to determine the need for a question ban. I would imagine though that this question didn't help. With `trackers` and `torrents` in the title, plus the fact it was closed, it certainly didn't help your odds. This is unfortunate since you say your intent was entirely legal. Despite that, it's definitely `Not Constructive`, as almost any question is when you say "What's the best `foo`?" The same goes for this question: `Which antivirus is good for my typical usage? [closed]`

---

#### Why is Kies not working?

#### Can't connect Galaxy S1 to Samsung kies that used to work

#### samsung kies 2 won't connect to my samsung galaxy 1

#### Why this driver cannot start?

That is a lot of questions about Kies! Despite owning a Galaxy S3 I can't say I know much about it. However, this pattern raises red flags for me. I want to say this is off topic for Super User, but I'm not 100% certain. In any case, you seem to have produced your own duplicates.

---

#### Need to configure perl

This seems to be a rather basic/broad question. Try asking more meaningful, pointed, and clear questions.

---

#### How to troubleshoot a dead Sony Vaio VPCSA?

#### Windows Vista can only boot into safe mode

#### crcdisk.sys won't load with Windows Vista

Nobody can teach you how to troubleshoot. You should try a few things, poke at your problem a while, and then post a question when you get stuck. Simply saying "It's broken! How do I fix it?" is not helpful for future visitors and almost impossible for community members to answer definitively. There's a lot of other places on the Internet where you can get troubleshooting help. Stack Exchange's Q&A format makes for a poor place to play guess-and-check. (Although we're perfectly happy to place guess-and-check at [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)!)

---

#### Why does Windows (Vista) “AppData” get so large? [closed]

This falls in to the `Not Constructive` category once more. While you do ask a technically valid question, it's not at all helpful. For example, my Evernote happens to use AppData to store the entirety of my notes and attachments on those notes. It's several gigabytes. What goes in the AppData folder depends on the applications one runs, and the data they need to store. Nobody would be able to give you a definitive answer for why AppData gets so large.

---

I really don't like to see SU used a dumping grounds for developers from SO who have computer problems. I have my own developers to support at work. ;) Try to give back to our community by answering some questions yourself, and please avoid thinking of Super User as a place for tech support. Much like the rest of SE, we like solid questions with clear answers. We have a very clear scope if you look around for a while, and many of your questions are either borderline or fall outside that scope.

I've upvoted some of your content in hopes of helping to lift your ban. Good luck!

Comment: Great post, but we *do* teach how to troubleshoot ;D http://superuser.com/questions/260043/how-do-i-troubleshoot-when-i-have-no-clue-where-to-start

Comment: Many thanks. I'm still cleaning and today I propsosed that my questions about error I think were random error should be deleted. If I had a random error it's unlikely to help other guys even if I solved it..